# Inputstream no such file directory-Android

Tags: android, uri, inputstream

I choose a text file from internal storage of Android e.g Sample.txt that convert the file to byte array using     **convertFileToByteArray( Uri documentUri)**

```
Context applicationContext = MainActivity.getContextOfApplication();
private byte[] convertFileToByteArray(Context context, Uri documentUri) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = applicationContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(documentUri);
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
        }
        buffer.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    return buffer.toByteArray();

}
```

In this line

```
InputStream inputStream = applicationContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(documentUri);
```

no catch on exception error however, it catch Exception and return "No such directory" when I choose a file that cannot be identified their extension type, for example, Sample.lev1, Sample.abc, Sample.rty

This android app is for encryption and decryption, so my extension for encrypted file would be weird, such as, .lev1, .abc, .rty.

Encryption are fine because I choose a file that can be readable (.txt, .pdf) but decryption no because when trying to convert file(.lev1, .abc, .rty) to byte array, it throws "FileNotFoundException",

```
case R.id.btnGO://WILL CRYPT file
                Uri doctUri = chosenFile;
                keyType = MainActivity.keyType;
                if (keyType == null || doctUri == null || radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
                    setMessage("Selection not Complete !");
                } else {
                    mimeType = getMimeType(getContext(), doctUri);//check file whether it suitable or not.
                    // and to be used for save file
                    if (functionCode == ENCRYPT_FILE) {
                        try {
                            if (mimeType == null || isBCDMimeType(getFileName(doctUri))) {
                                if (isBCDMimeType(getFileName(doctUri))) {

                                    //
                                } else {


                                }
                            } else {
                                byte[] b = convertFileToByteArray(doctUri);
                                launchRingDialogForEF(null, b, mimeType, keyType);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.getLocalizedMessage();
                        }
                    } else if (functionCode == DECRYPT_FILE) {
                        if (isVendorMimeType(getFileName(doctUri))) {

                            try {


                                 byte[] b = convertFileToByteArray(doctUri);
                                size = b.length;

                                encryptDecryptHex ead = new encryptDecryptHex();

                                ead.decrypt(usbDeviceConnection, epOUT, epIN, b);

                                returnEData = ead.deData;
                                output = ead.decryptedData;
                                showMessageAfterTryToCrypt(returnEData, output, "Decrypt File", ead.m, ead.k);//m= mimeType k=keyType
                                goOk(usbDeviceConnection, epOUT, epIN);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.getLocalizedMessage();
                            }
                        } else {

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Your OS version ? if 6.0 or greator have you get runtime permissions?

Comment: check your documentURI for if it contains correct path or not.

Comment: Can you include your code where you request the file and how that flow gets to your `convertFileToByteArray` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the uri for Encrypted.ab(for example) was appended by **"%00"**

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AEncrypted.a%00b%00%00%00%00%00
```

Answer (score 0):

You have get the permission at runtime before accessing any device storage if the os version is 6.0 and more. Check the following official documentation for more information
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: If so, why it can convert the file of .txt, .mp3, .pdf? but cannot convert the .lev1, .abc and .rty to byte array?

Comment: Wrong problem description. Your problem is that the content resolver does not open an inputstream for the choosen uri. It has nothing to do with encryption either so you can remove all that code. Better show the intent with wich the user chooses the file.